# Druid - Get top X records, sorted by time, grouped on a set of dimensions?

Tags: druid

Is it possible to get the top X records, sorted by time, grouped on a set of dimensions?

### Example:

This is a fictional example, that's meant to simply illustrate the problem.

Given a data source in the following format, how can I get the most recent 10 people to make a purchase, and their most recent purchase amount & product name?

So the result is 10 unique people, and their most recent purchase amount & product name.

Data source schema:

```
purchases
-----------------------------------------------------------------
timestamp   first_name    last_name   customer_id  product_name  purchase_amount
```

### Things I've tried:

#### Select query

This doesn't do any grouping, but does order the 10 most recent records by time.  Issue is they're not unique.

```
{
  "context": {
    "timeout": 8000
  },
  "queryType": "select",
  "dataSource": "purchases",
  "granularity": "all",
  "intervals": [ "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z/2017-04-23T00:00:00.000Z" ],
  "descending": "true",
  "pagingSpec": { "pageIdentifiers": {}, "threshold": 10 }
}
```

#### groupBy query

This groups by all dimensions and metrics, instead of just grouping on first_name, last_name, customer_id - and then taking the most recent product_name and purchase_amount.

So you will have 10 records, but they will not be 10 unique people. Just 10 unique combinations of the metrics & dimensions listed.

Also it's not ordered by time.

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "purchases",
  "granularity": "all",
  "intervals": [ "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z/2017-04-23T00:00:00.000Z" ],
  "dimensions": [
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "customer_id",
    "product_name"
  ],
  "metrics": [
    "purchase_amount"
  ],
  "limitSpec": { 
    "type": "default", 
    "limit": 10
  }
}
```